# Subscribe is deprecated: The declaration was marked as deprecated here

Tags: angular, rxjs

in visual studio code the subscribe appears with a line in the middle of it

```
obtenerProductos() {
    this.productoService.getProductos().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    }, error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

I was looking at something related to next: and error: but I don't know how to use it

Don't know exactly what should I use and how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new way to write that logic to keep the code clean:

```
obtenerProductos() {
    this.productoService.getProductos().subscribe({
        next: this._onSuccess.bind(this),
        error: this._onError.bind(this)
    });
}

public onSuccess(data) {
  foo();
}

public onError(error) {
  bar();
}
```

I haven't typed anything since it's an example, but I highly suggest you to always type your data.